# How to access vue.js via URL subdirectory by Nginx(Reverse proxy) + Nginx(Docker) + Vue.js(Docker)

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I would like to access `http://localhost/abc` of URL subdirectory by following routes.

`User --> Nginx(Reverse proxy) --> Nginx(Docker) --> Vue.js(Docker)`

However I can not.
I can access to `Nginx(Docker)` till.
But Nginx(Reverse proxy) is not working.

These are the codes and vue version.

```
$ vue --version
@vue/cli 4.0.5
```

If someone understands how to solve this issue, please let me know.

#### nginx.conf of Nginx(Reverse proxy)

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /abc {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:30030;
        }
    }
```

#### nginx.conf of Nginx(On Docker)

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 30030;
        charset utf-8;
        server_name localhost;
        index      index.html;
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    }
}
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "30030:30030"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 30030
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;","-c","/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

#### Vue.js(router/index.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/Home.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes,
})

export default router
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out? because im running into almost the same issue

Comment: Sorry late reply. I changed Vue to Nuxt then it is solved.